# Remove comment from yfinance?

Tags: python, yfinance

Every time I try to get ticker price using yFinance, it would print this comment:

```
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
```

Is there anyway to get rid of it?

```
data = yf.download(ticker, startDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), endDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [download method](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/eb42fbfbcd5beca3f08b1eb0dce59b6e531bb211/yfinance/multi.py#L32-L35)

```py
def download(tickers, start=None, end=None, actions=False, threads=True,
             group_by='column', auto_adjust=False, back_adjust=False,
             progress=True, period="max", interval="1d", prepost=False,
             proxy=None, rounding=False, **kwargs):
```

has an undocumented parameter called `progress` that you should be able to set to `False` to disable the progress bar.

Try changing your download call to:

```py
data = yf.download(
    ticker, startDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), endDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), progress=False)
```

Comment: What would the solution be if we used yfinance.pdr_override() ?